# Import full xml file into Google Sheets (ParseError)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like all data from an XML file imported to Google Sheets.
More specific it's a product feed containing data for all the products on an ecommerce store. I'd like all these data in a Google spreadsheet.

What's wrong in my formula?

=IMPORTXML("https://www.example.com/export/googlepla.xml")
=IMPORTXML("https://www.example.com/export/googlepla.xml", "/*")

The xml file start like this:

```
<channel>
<title>Google_Shopping_Feed</title>
<link>https://www.example.com/export/googlepla.xml</link>
<description> Google PLA Feed</description>
<item>
<g:id>12345-678912</g:id>
<title>Cool Sweatshirt</title>
<description>
...
</description>
<g:google_product_category>Apparel &amp; Accessories &gt; Clothing</g:google_product_category>
<g:product_type>Clothes > Sweatshirts</g:product_type>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<link>https://www.example.com/item/12345-cool-sweatshirt</link>
<g:image_link>https://www.example.com/library/12345-cool-sweatshirt.jpg</g:image_link>
<g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
<g:price>99.95 USD</g:price>
<g:brand>Coolio</g:brand>
<g:item_group_id>12345</g:item_group_id>
<g:gender>female</g:gender>
<g:color>WHITE</g:color>
<g:size>L</g:size>
</item>

I would like all the data for each product into each row.
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the sample URL for testing your formula and provide the sample output situation as an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a valid xml file.

Lets say you want to show all data from this xml:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Your formula will be:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml";"/note")
```

But if you want to show "Reminder", your formula will be:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml";"//heading")
```

mind the backslash.
Parent= /
Child= //

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrea!
It was a simple rookie mistake. **Semicolon** instead of **comma**